# Any abstract algebra book with programming (homework) assignment?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory, math-software, computational-algebra

All:

I had studied abstract algebra long time ago. Now, I would like to review some material, particularly about Galois theory (and its application).

Can anyone recommend an abstract algebra book which cover Galois theory (and its applications)?

I have been a software engineer for past many years. Ideally, I would like an algebra book with programming assignments or exercise (help me to understand concept.)  For example, homework assignments to write a program to verify Galois theory, or to construct 'solvable Group", or anything like that. (Of course, I can think some random questions, but I prefer a text book with well designed, and meaningful home works).

I felt that I was not good at deriving formula anymore, I would like to use my programming skills to help me to understand subject, do more hand-on exercise and calculations.

Comment: Interesting question.  Abstract algebra seems like a subject that could lend itself well to work involving computer software.  Here's an exercise for you.  Suppose you know that $a$ and $b$ are roots of two given polynomials whose coefficients are integers.  Write a program to find the minimal polynomial of $a+b$.

Comment: That's not a well-posed problem, Michael. :) Ask for some polynomial with root $a+b$.

Comment: ....um... @darijgrinberg : Do you mean the answer might depend on which of the roots of the two given polynomials are chosen? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @darijgrinberg : I suppose what I meant by minimal polynomial is a monic polynomial with rational coefficients having $a+b$ are a root.  There's only one of those (provided $a+b$ is well defined). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: While it doesn't cover Galois theory, *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by Cox, Little, and O'Shea (http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-0-387-35650-1) is an accessible intro to commutative algebra and algebraic geometry with an emphasis on writing programs for problem-solving.

Comment: In addition to *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms*, I came here to suggest *Abstract Algebra with GAP*. Sadly, it concludes with Galois theory. http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/gallian/abstract_algebra/6e/shared/gap/full_manual.pdf

Comment: Two more links: http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/howtogap.pdf http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Teaching/teaching.html

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Yes, it depends on the choice of the roots. For a stupid example, let $a$ and $b$ be roots of the *same* irreducible polynomial.

Comment: It is not an algebra book per se, but you may like at least parts of [Modern Computer Algebra](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/computer-science/algorithmics-complexity-computer-algebra-and-computational-g/modern-computer-algebra-3rd-edition) by J. von zur Gathen & J. Gerhard. It may be a bit more advanced than what you hope at times. At least to an extent a reference book rather than a book for learning the basics, so browse before you shop. A lot of pseudocode in there.

Comment: Another suggestion - [Abstract Algebra: An Interactive Approach](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781420094527) by William Paulsen.

Answer (score 4):

All books listed in the comments above are listed in my answer to the question [Novel approaches to elementary number theory and abstract algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947239/), so I am placing a CW-answer here to remove this question from the unanswered queue.