# Books on the GAP (groups, algorithms and programming) system

Tags: abstract-algebra, gap

I am learning GAP by using internet only for computations in finite group theory. Is there any book for GAP? I didn't find any such book.Thanks.

Comment: Which tutorials?............

Comment: I didn't understand about tutorials...

Comment: Please give some link

Comment: You may like to look at [Representations of Groups - A Computational Approach](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~RepresentationsOfGroups/) which has GAP examples.

Comment: Please see http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/doc.html - in particular "Learning GAP" and "Teaching materials". Hard to give more specific advise without further details.

Comment: @neelkanth see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947239/novel-approaches-to-elementary-number-theory-and-abstract-algebra/967298#967298